# How to change route in WebApi+Odata project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm re-implementing WCF service and I choose to use WebAPI 2.2 + OData v4. 
Problem I'm facing is that I need to have route which contains '_' and I'm unable to implement it. 
Currently I have this:

```
public class AnnotationSharedWithController : ODataController
{
    ...
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<AnnotationSharedWith> Get()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.AnnotationSharedWith.Get();
    }
    ...
}
```

and my WebApiConfig.cs looks like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("webservice",null,GenerateEdmModel());
        config.Count();
}

private static IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<AnnotationSharedWith>("annotation_shared_with");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

When I issue GET request I receive following error

> { "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:12854/annotation_shared_with'.", "MessageDetail":
>   "No type was found that matches the controller named
>   'annotation_shared_with'." }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could use routing attributes to achieve this:

1. Using [ODataRouteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.odatarouteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class:

   ```
   public class AnnotationSharedWithController : ODataController
   {
       [EnableQuery]
       [ODataRouteAttribute("annotation_shared_with")]
       public IQueryable<AnnotationSharedWith> Get()
       {
           //your code
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using [ODataRoutePrefixAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.odatarouteprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and [ODataRouteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.odatarouteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) classes:

   ```
   [ODataRoutePrefixAttribute("annotation_shared_with")]
   public class AnnotationSharedWithController : ODataController
   {
       [EnableQuery]
       [ODataRouteAttribute("")]
       public IQueryable<AnnotationSharedWith> Get()
       {
           //your code
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

By default OData will search for `annotation_shared_withController` as defined in your EDM Model. Since your controller is named `AnnotationSharedWithController` it will return `404`.

Renamaing your controller class will solve the issue. But you will end up with messy class names.

You can implement your own Routing Conventions, see
[Routing Conventions in ASP.NET Web API 2 Odata](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions) for more details

Hope it helps.